# How do I clear my randomly generated data to create new data in each file in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, while-loop, nested-loops

I've boiled down the logic of something I'm struggling to figure out (new to Python, been a long time since I've done any coding). I have the code below, the intention is to roll a d6 `limit` times (in this case 300) and then over a defined number of iterations generate a file with the resulting dice rolls for each 300 iterations into its own file.

What I get is n (`loops`) files with the same data in each one. So right now this will return random1.txt, random2.txt and random3.txt and all will have the same values in them.

Obviously I need to reinitialize `results`in some way at the start of each iteration of the parent while loop (`while loops >=1:`), I just can't figure out how.

If anyone can take pity on a blundering artist I'd appreciate it! This is part of an art project I'm working on to make generative art with an axidraw if anyone is curious.

```
import numpy as np
import os

loops = 3  # will generate n files
limit = 300    
throw = 1.0        
results = []

while loops >=1:
    loops -= 1
    while throw <= limit:   
        roll = np.random.randint(1, 7)
        throw += 1
        results.append(roll)

    n = 1
    while os.path.exists("random%s.txt" % n):
        n += 1

    listToStr = ' '.join(map(str, results))
    f = open("random%s.txt" % n, "w" )
    f.write(listToStr)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code for a blundering artist :-)

```
import numpy as np

nRolls = 8
for f in [1,2,3]:
    # Generate 8 rolls of the die
    rolls = np.random.randint(1,7,nRolls)
    # Save like a CSV
    np.savetxt(f'random{f}.txt', [rolls], delimiter=',', fmt='%d')
```

`random1.txt`

```
5,2,3,5,4,6,6,1
```

`random2.txt`

```
1,6,6,1,1,4,2,1
```

`random3.txt`

```
5,4,4,4,6,3,1,5
```